# UIAlertView showing up very slowly

Tags: ios4, uialertview

I just wrote a iOS app to test the UIAlertView. When I ran it, the UIAlertView just appear with the screen went dark first without the UIAlertView, and "a long time" later ,the UIAlertView appeared. This happens on both Simulator and iPhone (IOS 4.2). I don't know why, Please help me, thanks.

Description:(You can also download the Project [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/uialertview-test-slow/downloads/detail?name=SlowUITest.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges))

Its a very simple View based app With 3 Classes: AppDelgate ViewControler and a TestOperation which implement NSOperation; 
AppDelegate was just the one produced by XCode;
TestOperation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol TestOperationDelegate

- (void)didFinishTestOperaion;

@end


@interface TestOperation : NSOperation {
    id <TestOperationDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <TestOperationDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

TestOperation.m

```
#import "TestOperation.h"


@implementation TestOperation

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)main {
    [delegate didFinishTestOperaion];
}

@end
```

ViewContoller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    TestOperation *testOperation = [[TestOperation alloc] init];
    testOperation.delegate = self;
    [queue addOperation:testOperation];
    [testOperation release];
}

- (void)didFinishTestOperaion {
    NSLog(@"start uialertview");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Here's the UIAlertView" 
                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Confirm" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

> ***//Solved!! Use performSelectorOnMainThread to make
>   the UI run on Main Thread***

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below and accept it once you are able to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved!! Use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to make the UI run on Main Thread

> [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Answer (score 1):

What are you attempting to test in the UIAlertView? If you simply called the UIAlertView from viewDidAppear: in your ViewController, is the UIAlertView displayed rapidly as expected?

I expect that the issues you are having are related to how you are calling the UIAlertView, and that the UIAlertView is being displayed before the UIView controlled by your ViewController has appeared.

Comment: I add a button to the View and move the NSOperationQueue part to the Touch up button inside event listener to make sure the viewController has appeared.And when I touch the button, the UIAlertView still behave the same as before. If I just called the UIAlertView from viewDidLoad, it behave correctly.So I think maybe it's just because I use the delegate, but I don't know how to solve this.